The sign that should be taken for a centrifugal potential
This is my first post here so please comment if anything is unclear or misleading.
I would like to present a question from a test I head in statistical physics. I struggle to understand my mistake and would love some small explanation and maybe some advice as to how I could have known that I am wrong:

A centrifuge is a closed and sealed pipe that rotates about one of its edges at an angular speed $\omega$. Such a pipe is filled with two single atom ideal gases, one with atomic mass (the mass of a single atom) $m_1$ and the other is $m_2$. When the centrifuge isn't rotating the concentration of both gases is $n$. Give an expression of the ratio $\frac{n_1}{n_2}$ when the centrifuge is rotating (the centrifugal force acting on the gases is $m\omega^2 r$ and its direction is away from the center)

The way I solved this question is simply use the fact that in an equilibrium state, the effective chemical potential between the gases must be equal (or else some atoms would move and the concentration would change)
In general, the effective potential is the sum: $\mu + \phi$ where $\mu$ is the chemical potential and $\phi$ is some potential sourced by some outside force.
In this case we're speaking of ideal gases so $\mu = NK_B \ln(\frac{n}{n_Q}) $ where $n$ is the concentration of the gas (atoms per unit volume) and $n_Q$ is the quantum concentration. As for the "outer potential", I found it by using the relation: $$ \frac{d\phi}{dr} = F =m\omega^2r $$
Here we solve for $\phi$ taking the integration constant to be zero. I found $\phi = \frac{m\omega^2r^2}{2}$. I then wrote $\mu_1 + \phi_1 = \mu_2 + \phi_2$ and solved pretty simply for $\frac{n_1}{n_2}$ getting some exponential expression. The question was multiple choice and I found my answer in the options so I picked it. Apparently, my mistake was in the calculation of $\phi$, specifically in the sign of $\phi$. I think I should've taken $F$ to be negative, but I am not sure why exactly. Why is my solution wrong? Does the direction of $F$ implies it should be negative?
I am providing the following diagram that was given in the test to illustrate the system:

Hopefully this paints a clear picture of what I don't understand. Thanks a lot!

The conventional definition of the potential $\phi$ is such that
$$F = -\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{\mathrm{d}r}$$
hence the negative sign.
Reference: Chapter 6 of Dynamics and Relativity notes by David Tong, Eq. (6.7).

Wow, that sucks... I don't like multiple choice questions. All the points for misstating the definition of the potential.

@GamowDrop I've added a reference, which writes the equation in a slightly more general form.

Your definition applies only to a conservative force, no? The centripetal  force could, for example, be static friction

@BobD This formula is for the centrifugal force in a rotating frame at constant angular velocity. In such a case, the centrifugal force depends only on position and not velocity. It is indeed conservative and points cylindrically radially outward from the axis of rotation (see the section of the reference I linked).

@VincentThacker In this example the centrifuge is a contact force. It is my understanding contact forces are not conservative. Gravity, elastic, electrostatic, etc. forces are conservative.

@BobD I don't understand what contact force you are talking about. I am not talking about centripetal force. The centrifugal force $-m\vec{\omega}\times(\vec{\omega}\times\vec{r})$ is a fictitious force that arises in rotating frames. It acts on all objects simply because a rotating frame is non-inertial. In the case of constant angular velocity, it is conservative. Whether other forces are acting is irrelevant.

Update: I appealed and basically I got an answer that says - there is no convention, there should be minus sign and it shouldn't change the physical result. Well, I agree with the fact that whether I choose to put a minus sign in the potential or not the physical result shouldn't change but the definition is conventional as explained above. What I think is happening is that if one chooses to use the definition without minus sign it would affect the chemical potential so that it would include a minus sign and thus the result would fit the other case. @VincentThacker Can you confirm or deny?

@GamowDrop Yes, that is correct. Changing the sign of the potential cannot affect physics. If you remove the negative sign from the definition of force, you have to switch the signs of other potentials as well.

To the best of my knowledge the negative sign in the derivative is just a convention and have no real physical meaning as long as you are consistent with your choice.
the force would still be conservative with or without it, so unless I'm missing something it sounds like whoever graded it for you is a bit too set in their way and does not differentiate between a convention and physics.
that being said in physics the minus convention is usually easier to deal with as many of physical potentials are proportional to inverse distance, thus when you take the derivative you get a minus sign.
